# Xcode 7.3 Apple Ad Hoc distribution ask for Distribution manifest information

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution, xcode7.3, xcode-organizer

I want to export  my app with Ad Hoc distribution and save the resulting .ipa to file on my system as usual, but I can't because now using Organizer in Xcode 7.3 after choosing my archive export->Save for Ad Hoc Deployment the system show a "Distributed Manifest Information" form (see image below) where I have to choose an url and not the usual "Esport As" form.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Distributed Manifest Information is needed when you use on-demand resources in your app, otherwise you don't need to check “Include manifest for over-the-air installation”:

[image]

If you use them, you should fill this form as described in the docs:

> - Name. The name of the app displayed during download and installation.
> - App URL. A fully qualified HTTPS URL for the iOS App file.
> - Display Image URL. A fully qualified HTTPS URL for an app icon that    is displayed during download and installation. The image file must be 
>     57 x 57 pixels and in PNG format.
> - Full Size Image URL. A fully qualified HTTPS URL for a larger image    that is displayed in iTunes. The image file must be 512 x 512 pixels
>     and in PNG format.

Check this link for more info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Hope it helps)

Comment: Help me too.Thanks.